# Angular.JS makes window.onbeforeunload fails with 'Too much time spent in unload handler' in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I have simple *very* simple Vanilla JS to prompt before reloading / back.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Yes, there's no Angular here, but hold on....

On a non-Angular page, this works correctly and prompts when the user hits the back/reload buttons.

However on a Angular page, this fails with the following message:

```
Uncaught Error: Too much time spent in unload handler. v8/DateExtension:1
getTimeOverride v8/DateExtension:1
jQuery.extend.now jquery.js:838
jQuery.Event jquery.js:3268
jQuery.event.trigger jquery.js:2877
jQuery.fn.extend.triggerHandler jquery.js:3604
removePatch angular.js:1563
Base.extend.destroy WidgetView.js:364
Base.extend.destroy Widget.js:244
Base.extend.destroy Widget.js:240
window.onunload main.js:14
```

Comment: I suspect that page has a widget with its own unload handler, and it's interfering.

Comment: @Barmar I think you're right, I just noticed Angular in the stack trace...

Comment: @Barmar If you like, convert that to an answer and I'll delete my comments and give you a tick.